# MySQL tables - Deleting Old Rows

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've got a Wordpress site. And some of the database tables are getting large--from data collected by the plug-ins. I know of two ways to delete this data:

1. I can delete rows manually--1000 at a time--in phpmyadmin.
2. I can empty the whole table in phpmyadmin.

What I'm looking for is a third way, so that I can delete just the data collected before a certain time period.

As noted above, I know that I can sort the rows by date and delete 1000 at a time--to get rid of old ones.  But, there are over a million rows.  Is there a single procedure I can use to delete--for example--all of the rows that are more than 60 days old?

Comment: Did you try to take a look at the DELETE statement in SQL? I think this could be your third way.

Comment: I do not know the Wordpress tables, but phpMyAdmin lets you use SQL statments. You need a "DELETE FROM table WHERE ...". Be aware though, that deleting rows does not immediately make your database shrink. You will need to backup and restore for this.

Comment: You do not need to backup and restore. You can use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to rebuild it.

Comment: That's right! A backup is probably useful before the deletion.

Comment: @user2258740 Please post DDL (`CREATE TABLE` statement) for your table, or at least parts of it relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

To delete records that are more than 60 days old you can do something like this

```
DELETE 
  FROM table1
 WHERE datefield < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa931/1)**

Comment: Very important for this answer to work is the existence of a datefield. The OP does not specify this.

Comment: @user2258740 Did it help? Do you need more help with the question?